# Pytorch: Extract value from tensor if it's a tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a variable initialized at e.g var = 0, the algorithm changes this variable to a tensor type Int if some conditions are met, otherwise it will stay at zero. I want to just print the variable without the tensor wrapping, however, if I use:

```
var = 0
if random.uniform(0, 1) < 0.5:
   var = torch.IntTensor(1)
print (f' var: {var.item()}')
```

It will throw an error that 'var' doesn't have function item() when the if condition is > 0.5 as it's just a zero. Is there a way to print the 'var' variable without any checking conditions?

I'm looking to do this without an else statement and with the print function outside the condition, also by adding no code in the if statement.

Does a PyTorch function, similar to item(), that can automatically detect whether its a tensor or not and deal with the condition exist?

For example a potential solution that still uses an if else statement is:

```
print (f'var = {var if isinstance(var ,int) else var.item()}')
```

But it's not neat.

Comment: `print (f' var: {int(var)}')` ?

Answer (score 0):

A very obvious solution would be to use `try`

as in

```
var = 0
if random.uniform(0, 1) < 0.5:
   try:
       var = torch.IntTensor(1)
   except:
       pass # Or Throw and exception or whatever your use case migth be

print (f' var: {var.item()}')
```

This will *try* to run the IntTensor function, which if it gives an exception, it will handle.

You can also get the type of a variable by running type( variable ) which in case of `0` will return <class 'int'>, so you can add that to the if as well.

Python has a builtin method to get the type of a variable `type()`

```
type( 0 ) == int
```

Look into [Try-catch](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) And [Get-type](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_type.asp)

Comment: maybe I should have been more clear, i can't add any code in the if statement, however the get-type solution is a step in the right direction

Comment: No worries, you could even wrap the whole if statement in a try-catch but then you'd have to only catch the specfic error, but generally the type() way is considered to be better practice.